# i am using asus k501u and i lost my password

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, hard-drive, boot, passwords

My Asus K501U was running Win10 and i forgot my password and could not login.
I do not know how to setup the laptop to bootup from the external CD ROM. The external CD Drive is SAMSUNG.
I had done the below:

1. Secure Boot menu - Secure Boot Control [Disabled]
2. Launch CSM [Enabled]
3. Plug in the Samsung CD drive with the Win10 bootup disk.
4. Power on and pressing 'esc'
5. On the screen can only see 'Windows Boot Manager'
6. Selected 'Enter Setup'
7. Selected 'Boot' ---> Add New Boot Option' ---> 'Please advise me what i should type here'

Thank You
Ken Cheong

Answer (score 0):

If you're seeing the Windows Boot Manager, then it is too late for you to boot off of the CD drive, as the computer has already booted off of the internal storage.

You need to enter the BIOS, which is where you disabled secure boot and such.  In there, there will be a tab that says "Save and Exit" or similar.  In that tab, you can override the boot order.  It will have a list of available boot devices, so all you need to do is set your CD drive so that it is first on the list, and then let the computer reboot.  It will likely be named SAMSUNG with a serial or model number.  Your computer should then boot off of the CD drive.

You can also set the boot device without entering BIOS.  There is usually a key to override the boot order, which you must press as the computer turns on, similar to how you press a key to enter the BIOS.  They keys are different for different computers, but you could try pressing F2, F12, or Escape to see if any of those work.